# Diophantine equations,is that what I have done right?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I have solved the following diophantine equations:

- $14x+35y=93$
- $56x+72y=40$

That's what I have tried:

- $gcd(35,14)=7$ , but $7 \nmid 93,$ so the first diophantine equation has no solution.
- $gcd(56,72)=8$, $8 \mid 40$,so the diophantine equation  $56x+72y=40$ has infinite solutions.
  We are looking for $x_0,y_0$ such that $56x_0+72y_0=8$.This relation is satisfied for $x_0=4,y_0=-3$.

So, $x_1=20, y=-15$ is a solution of $56x+72y=40$.

Therefore, the solutions of this diophantine equation are given by the formulas:

$$x=20+7k, y=-15-9k, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Could you tell me if that I have tried is right?

Comment: You've misplaced the factors of $k$ at the end, $x = 20 + 9k$ and $y = -15 - 7k$ is correct, since $9\cdot 56 - 7\cdot 72 = 0$. Apart from that glitch, it's good.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh,yes!!! You are right!!! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: You might as well rewrite the second equation as $7x+9y = 5.$ This does not affect the pairs $(x,y)$ for which the equation is valid. Keeping the numbers smaller when possible reduces the odds of making an error, especially with computations by hand.